# Error when windows startup for pm2 startup script

Tags: node.js, pm2

I got the error below. How can I config pm2 that disable the window startup task?
Showing cannot find script file `invisible.vbs`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the *pm2-windows-startup* [source](https://github.com/marklagendijk/node-pm2-windows-startup/blob/master/index.js), we can see the possible arguments we can pass to the module.

You can try `pm2-startup uninstall` command.
This should remove the corresponding registry entry.

Or if you want to keep *pm2-startup* script, you can try to reinstall it globally or add missing invisible.vbs file in your node_modules\pm2-windows-startup folder.

---

If it is due to file missing issue, we can install that package and do `pm2-startup uninstall`. It tells pm2 remove the startup task. That way should fix the file missing issue in this case.

Comment: Hi, I checked, I do not have node_modules\pm2-windows-startup folder

Comment: Yes, it might be the problem indeed. Have you tried to reinstall it and launch the `pm2-startup uninstall` command?

Comment: `C:\Repo\vcm-spa>pm2-startup uninstall
Successfully removed PM2 startup registry entry.` that may help my case, I will let you know next time i do hard laptop restart. thanks

Comment: Hey it works that way, I will update your answer and accept it. Thanks, mate